# Proof involving prime factorization

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, prime-factorization

I'm beginning some self-study in Number Theory and have come across a problem that I'm not really sure how to solve. Here's the problem:

> Prove that, if,
>
> $$
> a=q_{1}^{e_{1}}q_{2}^{e_{2}} . . . q_{r}^{e_{r}}
> $$
>   $$
> b=s_{1}^{f_{1}}s_{2}^{f_{2}} . . . s_{u}^{f_{u}}
> $$
>
> are the factorizations of $a$ and $b$ into primes, where $q_{1}<q_{2}<...<q_{r}$ and $ s_{1}<s_{2}<...<s_{u}$, then there exist primes $t_{1}<t_{2}< . . . <t_{v}$ and non-negative integers $q_{i}$ and $h_{i}$ such that:
>
> $$
> a=t_{1}^{h_{1}}t_{2}^{h_{2}} . . . t_{v}^{h_{v}}
> $$
>   $$
> b=t_{1}^{q_{1}}t_{2}^{q_{2}} . . . t_{v}^{q_{v}}
> $$

As someone who is relatively new to studying mathematics, I normally try to explain what the problem means in words when I begin trying to solve it. The way I understand it, this problem is asking you to prove that any two numbers can be represented as powers of the same number of primes, namely, $v$.

Intuitively, this makes sense. The way I justified it to myself is as follows... some massive prime, $P$, and 3 can be represented this way:

$$
3=(2^0)(3^1)(5^0) . . . (P^0)
$$
$$
P=(2^0)(3^0)(5^0) . . . (P^1)
$$

Where, $v=\pi(P)$. Thus, no matter how big the difference between $a$ and $b$, it would still hold.

My problem is that I'm not really sure where to begin with constructing a proof, so I'm asking for some guidance or advice.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Looks to me, at first glance at least, that you understand very well, and have seen the idea of the proof. In cases like this, fussy details that must be dealt with will often get in the way of a neat argument. I suggest that perhaps your first remark will be to say that you might as well assume that the $q$’s and the $s$’s are already in ascending order.

Comment: This is a nice induction exercise, and it gets fun only if you *don't* assume the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to be true.